# Rendering multiple base64 images with Angular 4 causes performance problems

Tags: javascript, html, image, angular, base64

I'm on a project for a private application and we're using Angular 4 (currently 4.1.2 version) and we have a page where multiple base64 images are being rendered on html. The problem is: When these images are loaded there's a hude drop in performance.

To be more specific, we receive these images from a rest service, and load the images inside a table using something like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let i of dataArray;">
    <td>
       <span>
         <img [src]="i.avatar !== null && i.avatar !== undefined ? 'data:image/png;base64,'+i.avatar : 'assets/img/avatar.png'">
       </span>
    </td>
<tr>
```

There's some kind of optimization that could be done, or something that i'm missing here? As I said, when these images are loaded (there are about 30 images), all the application gets laggy, the menu almost stops working makes any action very hard to be executed. This is happening on both Chrome and Firefox, and to be honest I'm not sure if this is a Angular, Html or what issue.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt this is related to angular, that's just the browser being busy doing work. I'd try to add the values one by one with some delay to `dataArray`. You can use the load event like `<img [src]="..." (load)="addNext()">` to add one only after the previous was loaded.

Comment: A trick I recently learned.  Draw the image to a canvas instead.

Comment: it's slow because you re-render each digest, and dataURL's aren't cached. pre-cache them, don't template in-dom, or use a smart renderer like react.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draw to a canvas instead, weirdly it uses less memory

HTML:

```
<canvas id='displayImage' ></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
    var img = new Image;

    img.onload(function(
       var cv=document.getElementById("displayImage");
       cv.width = this.naturalWidth;
       cv.height = this.naturalHeight;
       cv.getContext("2d").drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    ));
    img.src="base64 Image string";
```

Using this trick, I saved about a gig of RAM per image, and cut processing by 1/100th.

If you want to get fancy, you can use your existing code, but attach a load event that takes the image, puts it on a canvas, removes the image element and places the canvas there.  This way each time an image is added, it gets automatically turned into a canvas.